# Syntax for handling parameters dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A series of parameters are being submitted to a Rails controller:

```
"25"=>"true", "30"=>"false", "35"=>"true", "40"=>"true", "45"=>"true", "50"=>"true", "55"=>"true", "60"=>"true", "65"=>"false", "70"=>"true", "75"=>"true", "80"=>"false", "100"=>"true"
```

The goal is to loop through:

```
@age_limits = [25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,100]
```

and process based on each param's value.

The problem is that the syntax for referring to the param is evading me:

```
@age_limits.each do |limit|
  puts params[:"#{limit}"]
  if params[:"#{limit}"] == "true"
    session[:demographic_agegroups] << params[:"#{limit}"]
    puts session[:demographic_agegroups]
  end
end
```

Both `params[:"#{limit}"]` and `params[":#{limit}"]` do not allow to access the parameter.  The former will return the value by putting into console (*editor BBEdit does not consider it properly formed Ruby*), but will not allow to process in its basis.

How can the controller properly access the param and process based on its value?

Comment: What about to `params["#{limit}"]` ? From your output, its simple string and you can use `limit.to_s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r missing to convert `int` to `string`.

Since your params keys are string, you can use `params[limit.to_s]`.

Also, if its key based `"keyX".to_sym` would be `:keyX`

Comment: Useful.  Succinct. I am surprised that a symbol that gets handled that way.